# using wget or curl to test website's .htaccess + robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, curl, wget, robots.txt

I am trying to debug my website's .htaccess + robots.txt, I want to use cURL or wget to try to access files that I blocked using robots.txt or pages that should redirect to another location via .htaccess

I have the following in my robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp/wp-admin/
```

yet, I still be able to crawl it

wget

```
$ wget http://xxxx.com/wp/wp-admin/
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2017-08-28 07:37:05--  http://xxxx.com/wp/wp-admin/
Resolving xxxx.com... 118.127.47.249
Connecting to xxxx.com|118.127.47.249|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://xxxx.com/wp/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fxxxx.com%2Fwp%2Fwp-
admin%2F&reauth=1 [following]
--2017-08-28 07:37:12--  http://xxxx.com/wp/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fxxxx.com%2Fwp%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
Connecting to xxxx.com|118.127.47.249|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2891 (2.8K) [text/html]
Saving to: `wp-login.php@redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fxxxx.com%2Fwp%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1'

100%[==============================================================================>] 2,891       --.-K/s   in 0.1s

2017-08-28 07:37:17 (22.2 KB/s) - `wp-login.php@redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fxxxx.com%2Fwp%2Fwp-admin%2F&re
auth=1' saved [2891/2891]
```

curl

```
$ curl -L xxx.com/wp/wp-admin -o wp-admin.html
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1147  100  1147    0     0    107      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:--   280
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:37 --:--:--     0
100  2891  100  2891    0     0     17      0  0:02:50  0:02:42  0:00:08   234
```

neither wget nor curl respected robots.txt
Is there a way to check how my .htaccess+robots.txt? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

robots.txt is purely for search engine bots, it is ignored by most user browsers *[including wget and curl]*, if you want to check that your robots.txt is parseable you can use google's checker in the webmaster console, which shows any errors and issues which may exist with your robots.txt file.

Redirects using .htaccess should work with any browser, and wget should show these redirects.

Comment: are there other tools other than google console, I am trying to simulate a specfic .txt file in my website, to see if they are casually crawleable by google?

Comment: https://en.ryte.com/free-tools/robots-txt/ might help, but you can't use robots.txt to hide stuff you want to stay private, because if anyone is looking 
then robots is one of the first places they will look for things you are trying to hide.

Comment: actually I am not trying to hide, I actually, deliberately want to know if a `.txt` file in my website can be accessed/crawled by bots

Comment: It depends which bots you want to check for, the link I provided works for some well behaved bots, but for others you will need to check A) The bot respects robots.txt, and B) What the user agent is, if you want to block other bots

Comment: bzzt - Wget WILL test robots.txt exclusion. There are a large number of wget options that are available from .wgetrc but not normally on the command line. To turn the relevant option on or off, use the -e flag, e.g. wget -e robots=on ... 
 It must not be working for some other reason. The first thing to check is the UserAgent string sent by wget, as the default may very well be being mis-classified by robots.txt. Perhaps you want to modify the UserAgent string used by wget to explicitly include Googlebot/1.0.